# Bring the latest commented topic on top on forum index page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building a forum. I want to bring published topics on top whenever users leave a reply. For topics without replies, I want to order them by `created_at` column.

How do you do that?

Forum controller

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
  $topics = Topic::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
  $query->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc');
  }])->paginate(20);
}
```

Here is my topic table

```
Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is my comment table

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->text('reply');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();


        $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('topic_id')->refrenced('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
```

Comments model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'reply',
        'user_id',
        'topic_id'
    ];


    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Topic model

```
class topic extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
       'title',
       'body',
       'category_id'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\category');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

}
```

still trying to figure this out. any help will be hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using eager load with constraint:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $topics = Topic::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->paginate(20);

    return view('forums.index',compact('categories','topics'));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I had tried that and l left a reply on my second post to see if the topic comes first on the index page but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('topics')
->leftjoin('comments', function($join) {
                    $join->on('topics.id', '=', 'comments.topic_id');
                })
->select(DB::raw('IF(comments.id IS NULL,0, 1) as topic_comment'))
->orderBy('topic_comment', 'DESC')
->orderBy('topics.created_at', 'DESC')
->get();

the topic_comment as 1 records you can show on top right and rest wherever you want
```